# Unable to create process in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt

Facing an error while opening anaconda prompt. Error says
`unable to create process`

I have been using python since long and did not face this error before. It popped up just recently.

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiEMS.png)

Comment: Why do you try to install the packages with `pip` in conda environment?

Comment: Agreed. but that's not the point. The problem is that its throwing the error when i try conda install too.

Comment: Also, today I had installed docker on my laptop. Can that be a source of conflict?